# Join with object from a collection array result

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have 2 collections:

Users: uid, displayName.

Activities: documents that the user can create. It also contains userUid with their references to the Users collection

I get the activities like that:

```
this.activities = this.afs.collection<Activity>('activities')
 .snapshotChanges()
 .pipe(
   map((actions) => {
    return actions.map((a) => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data();
      data.uid = a.payload.doc.id;
      return data;
    })
  }));
```

So, my question is how is the best way to join and get also the user data?

I tried like that:

```
actReference.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map((actions) => {
    return actions.map((a) => {
      const actData = a.payload.doc.data();
      actData.uid = a.payload.doc.id;

      return this.userService.getUserDocById(actData.userUid).snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
          map((userActions) => {
            const userData = userActions.payload.data();
            return { user: { uid: userData.uid, displayName: userData.displayName }, ...actData };
          }))
    })
  }));
```

But it returns me an

```
 Observable<Observable<Activity>[]>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply rxjs pipe operator chaining.

```
actReference.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map((actions) => {
    actions.map((a) => ({
      let actData = a.payload.doc.data();
      actData.uid = a.payload.doc.id;
      actData.displayName = a.payload.doc.name;
      return actData;
    });
  }),
  map((userData) => {
      return this.userService.getUserDocById(actData.userUid).snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
          map((userActions) => {
            const userData = userActions.payload.data();
            return { user: { uid: userData.uid, displayName: userData.displayName }, ...actData };
          }))
    })
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

@suresh-kumar-ariya answer was not my final result but helped me a lot, I end up with this code:

```
 return actReference.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map((actions) => {
    return actions.map((a) => {
      const actData = a.payload.doc.data();
      actData.uid = a.payload.doc.id;

      return this.userService.getUserDocById(actData.userUid).snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
          map((userActions) => {
            const userData = userActions.payload.data();
            return { user: { uid: userData.uid, displayName: userData.displayName }, ...actData } as Activity;
          }))
    })
  }),
  mergeMap(obs => combineLatest(obs))
);
```